# gdb failed to load sharedlibrary

Tags: debug, gdb

I had this problem when trying to decode a corefile generated by a system crash.

But after I load the corefile and debug symbol of my main process, I found the gdb did not load any of sharedlibrary or .so at all.

Even I tried to load them manually, but any sharedlibrary related cmd would get a return like below:

```
(gdb) sharedlibrary
Cannot access memory at address 0x20202024
Cannot access memory at address 0x20202020
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
Cannot access memory at address 0x20202024
Cannot access memory at address 0x20202020
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be mutliple reasons for this issue.
1. check if the binary which caused this core file is rebuild.
2. Check if your loading correct ld (show solib-search-path or show sysroot).